# Simplest horrorss code doesn't run

Tags: java, rss

I am using the Java RSS parser [horrorss](http://code.google.com/p/horrorss/)
I added horrorss-2.2.0.jar to my Build path in Eclipse.

I can't even get the Simplest bit of Code to run.

```
import org.horrabin.horrorss.*;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

      RssParser rss = new RssParser();

      try{
              RssFeed feed = rss.load("http://rss.slashdot.org/Slashdot/slashdot");

              // Gets the channel information of the feed and 
              // display its title
              RssChannelBean channel = feed.getChannel();
              System.out.println("Feed Title: " + channel.getTitle());


      }catch(Exception e){
              System.err.println(e);
      }


}
}
```

The Console Output is always the following

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/hp/hpl/sparta/Parser
    at org.horrabin.horrorss.RssParser.parseFromReader(RssParser.java:431)
    at org.horrabin.horrorss.RssParser.parseFromURL(RssParser.java:455)
    at org.horrabin.horrorss.RssParser.load(RssParser.java:115)
    at org.horrabin.horrorss.RssParser.load(RssParser.java:147)
    at Test.main(Test.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hp.hpl.sparta.Parser
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 5 more
```

I hope you guys are able to help me out (or show me another nice method for Handling RSS Feeds in Java)

Comment: You are confusing two things. Your code _does_ compile. But it doesn't _run_. First obvious question: do you have all necessary jars in your classpath? Seems the answer to this one is no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you read this on the homepage?

> It requires Sparta-XML, a light-weight XML parser based on XPath.

You need to get the Sparta-XML jar and add that to the eclipse build path too.